# document.getElementsByClassName('name') has a length of 0

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to retrieve all the elements by class name by using the method getElementsByClassName (no jQuery). Console.log shows the array of the elements, but when I try to get the length of the array, it returns 0.

Saw a previous post with a similar problem that provided a solution of making sure that the element exists. I took this into consideration and fire the function after DOMcreation.

What is going on here?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    // Load current todo items from db
    loadTodoItems();

    var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addItem);

    var removeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("remove-btn");
    console.log(removeButton);
    console.log(removeButton.length);


}, false)
```

Another issue to note, is that I am noticing that in chrome Dev Tools when I look at the head tag, I'm seeing that some sort of angular code is being loaded in a script tag in the head, while the content that should be in my head tag are being loaded in the body. I am not using angular for my app.

Edit. Here is my HTML. It is in Jade:

Layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
head
   meta(charset="utf-8")
   title To Do List
   link(rel="stylesheet" href="main.css")

body
    block content
    script(src="main.js")
```

index.jade:
    extends layout

```
block content
    div.container
        h1 Get-Er-Done! 

        form#todo-form(role="form" method="POST" action="/todo")
            div.form-group
                label(for="addToDo") Add To-Do item:
                input#todoItemText.form-control(type="text")
                button(type="submit")#submit-btn.btn.btn-default Add

        ul#todo-list
```

Edit. The remove button is for the new todo item. This is called every time the user clicks add to post the new item.

```
function renderItems(items){
// Before rendering todo-items, clear the existing items in the list
var list = document.getElementById('todo-list');
while(list.hasChildNodes()){
    list.removeChild(list.lastChild);
}

// Loop through items
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("li");

    var removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    var btnText = document.createTextNode('Done');
    removeBtn.appendChild(btnText);
    removeBtn.className = 'remove-btn';

    var newItemText = document.createTextNode(items[i].item);
    el.appendChild(newItemText); // Add new content to new div
    el.appendChild(removeBtn);


    // To-Do list to append to 
    list.appendChild(el);
}
}
```

Comment: please show your html.

Comment: "some sort of angular code is being loaded in a script tag in the head … I am not using angular for my app", are you running your "app" on some website like jsbin, or jsfiddle?

Comment: I am not running my app on jsbin or jsfiddle. Just running it on my local server using NodeJS/Express

Comment: i don't see the element with the class `remove-btn` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Length is `0` because when you run it there's no element with class `remove-btn`. You can see the items in the console because `getElementsByClassName` returns a live `HTMLCollection`, which is updated when new elements are added.

The problem is that you create the elements with that class in `renderItems`, which runs after you run `getElementsByClassName`.

You can fix it using

```
function renderItems(items){
    var list = document.getElementById('todo-list');
    while(list.hasChildNodes()){/* ... */}
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {/* ... */}


    // Load current todo items from db
    loadTodoItems();

    var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addItem);

    var removeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("remove-btn");
    console.log(removeButton);
    console.log(removeButton.length);

}
```